# Bash prompt display HH:MM:SS

Tags: ps1

I learned from the question [date - HH:MM:SS (with AM/PM) 12 Hour Timestamp for Bash Prompt - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296008/hhmmss-with-am-pm-12-hour-timestamp-for-bash-prompt) and fine-tune my prompt as:

```
export PS1='\D{%r}:\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]:\n$ '
08:52:31 PM:me@host:~:
$
```

The time format is not very comfortable, the result I desire is

```
   08:52PM me@host~:
```

How could I get such a HH:MM(AM/PM) format\

The final result

```
export  PS1='\D{%I:%M%p %d/%m %A}:\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]:\n$ '

10:45PM 18/03 Monday:me@host:~:
```

$ ls
'$tty'

Comment: Why is the format in your question title different from what you actually want in the question?

Comment: @Alice You should not post answers in the question body. If you want to share what is the final solution that you used you can post your own answer. It's okay to answer your own question, if your answer adds something to the answers already present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The supported formats are those documented in `man date`. So instead of

```
   %r     locale's 12-hour clock time (e.g., 11:11:04 PM)
```

you can use

```
   %I     hour (01..12)
   %M     minute (00..59)
   %p     locale's equivalent of either AM or PM; blank if not known
```

So change `\D{%r}` to `\D{%I:%M%p}`

Answer (score 4):

Use `\@` (the current time in 12-hour am/pm format) instead of `\D{%r}`, that produces times in `HH:MM (AM|PM)` format.